# how to query core data object with specific attribute value

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data entity with many attributes and I need to be able to access them based on the value of one attribute.  For example I have an attribute "Trip" and I need to be able to access the values of the others based on the value of "Trip".  So I need to fetch all the values for any object that has a "Trip" value of 1.  How do I go about specifying this in the code?

Comment: Did you have a look at ["Fetching Managed Objects"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1) in the "Core Data Programming Guide" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty basic question. You can use a [`NSFetchRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html):

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"trip == %@", yourTrip];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Trips" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```